# How to call custom function outside from the admin page?

Tags: php, functions

I've created a function but i have some problems with it...

```
 echo get_option( 'my_function', 'custom_logo' );
```

I try to use this in my code but it returns me an array not a string.

When i use `echo $options['custom_logo'];` on my plugin backend admin page the code returns the value as a string.

So how can i call it from my theme for example?

Comment: You saved a _function_ to the options table under the key `my_function`?

Comment: yes i did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of context, it is hard to say anything definitive. There is a lot of information missing.

If you saved an `Array` to the `$wpdb->options` table (`add_option` or `update_option`) then `get_option` will return an `Array`. If you saved a string, it will return a string. If you want a string then you are *saving* the option incorrectly, but you haven't posted the code that saves this value.

As far as `$options['custom_logo']` being correct, without knowing how the `$options` array was created I don't know what to say.

Comment: the problem was i didn't declared `$options` like `$options = get_option('my_plugin');
$custom_url = $options['custom_logo'];`

that resolved the problem.